# Keeping a link inside a iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am trying to use Iframes and or PHP to hide a link that is dynamically created.  The link is being created in php.  But when I try to access that link from within an iframe it takes over the whole page.  The site loads, but the idea is that if it was in an iframe the url could be hidden and the user could click multiple items with out having to enter all their form data in every time.

I've tried using the link as a header and using php commands like:
$remote = fopen( $URL, "r");fpassthru($remote);
where $URL was my link.

a sample of the link is:
http://fb-zc-0.cafe.zynga.com/current/iframe//mfs_sent.php?ids=2&tab_clicked=All&request_id=236973056431070&gid=3014&today=1&time=3&ref=gift_today&cafe_token=OAlF7gSlMbQxAtBhvnprTzNhIww8H7Aq2z9i3KJwGWmJzUQfxZ8b9/kFWMVqN62JUihQA06VtuuoKoxmosK6JIPKWTMl0oQecLb+0e0HSAk3S32f5BCI7xhYB9SflOnN&from_page=SUNRISE_BREAKFAST_1&kingdom=quest&phylum=baklava&uid=342&sendkey=8e4aa1a75594c47cc61aee301efff90e$$ccF(NUP,67jiH3QM7!nspE0W8d8KprzD5,Za77bp34G*S_ST)*ilx)F7Y)acC4xj971Kkswxx2OM3eij3z1h0M3eij3z1h0&mode=quest_asking&quest_key=SUNRISE_BREAKFAST_1&mfs_time=3&snood=1&ajax=true&limiter_channel=rsvp&limiter_type=build_a_carnival3+5

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try &lt;href=... target='_self'>...</a>

Answer (score 1):

If you have links outside of this iFrame and want them to load into that iFrame on the same page, you'll have to give it a name, then target the named iFrame within your link's href.

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" name="myframe" hieght="100" width="100"></iframe>
<br/>
<a href="http://reddit.com" target="myframe">Test</a>.
```

However, if you're loading a page into your iFrame that's loading links with target="blank", then those will go to a new window; unless you don't have access to those pages, you won't be able to change the links (short of writing JS to dive into your iFrame, etc).

Comment: I am not using the blank I am assigning the iframe as mentioned but when the "Test" link is clicked the iframe takes over the whole window.  i.e.  I have 2 iframes one is 70% of the window and the other is next to it on the right.  The href line is on the left window and is supposed to change only the right frame.  But when the right frame is changed to my FB link it takes over the whole webpage.

Comment: You can use what I suggested before or it maybe that Facebook is using a frame breakout script so it removes your iframe.

Comment: The target="_self" doesn't work either unfortunately.  What's frustrating is that I know it can be done as there are a couple of other sites doing it.  Just can't seem to get it to work with mine.  I know that the others are calling a PHP file within their iframe which is what I'm trying as well.  and my php file is loading the link and executing with the fopen command.  I've also tried making the header of the php file the link with no effect.  I know that it is going to end up being something simple just not sure what.